# SparkContext not serializable when filling IndexedRowMatrix with random values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to fill of a matrix to check some work in spark using computeSVD method of the IndexedRowMatrix. This is the code I am using:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.{IndexedRow, IndexedRowMatrix}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import scala.util.Random

val nCol = 2000
val nRow = 10000

val numbers: Seq[Int] = (0 until nRow).toSeq 
val numbersRDD: RDD[Int] = sc.parallelize(numbers) 
val indexedRowRDD = numbersRDD.
  map(number => new Random(number)).
  map(random => Array.fill(nCol){random.nextDouble()}).
  map(values => new IndexedRow(1, Vectors.dense(values))).
  cache
```

When I execute it on spark, it yields the following exception in the map that fills the array with random doubles:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2094)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:370)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:369)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:369)
  ... 52 elided
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.SparkContext, value: org.apache.spark.SparkContext@62264d4f)
    - field (class: $iw, name: sparkContext, type: class org.apache.spark.SparkContext)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@ab5d5c8)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@99ace98)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@1a99d328)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@140e003e)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@43f4621b)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@1ac9c3cc)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@5078e308)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@45382749)
    - field (class: $line19.$read, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $line19.$read, $line19.$read@3695e4f2)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $line19$read, type: class $line19.$read)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@12418d3f)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $outer, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@71077d1)
    - field (class: $anonfun$2, name: $outer, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $anonfun$2, <function1>)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
  ... 61 more
```

I cannot see why is SparkContext being serialised and thus, spark complains about SparkContext being not serializable.

Comment: Looks like the use of `nCol` in a function passed to `RDD.map` closes over the object which contains the `nCol` definition, which also contains a reference to the `SparkContext`. Which means - Spark tries to serialize the object containing `nCol` and therefore tries to serialize the non-serializable `SparkContext`. Try inlining `nCol` (replace reference to it with its value, `2000`) just to see if that's the case. If so - you'll have to define in a separate `object` or as a local method value.

Comment: That was it. The code now works as expected. Thanks.